# How to redirect to same or homepage after logged in?

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I want to keep homepage or same page after customer logged in their account. Could anyone please tell where I have to change code in customer page. Please check my code:

```
<?php if( $isLoggedIn ) { ?>                                        
<li class="first">
    <a id="quick_sigup_link" style="positon:relative;" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>">
     <span>Hello. User</span>
     <span class="youraccount" style="margin-top:-25px;">My Account</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can change the options for the page which the customer remains on once logged in within the standard Magento settings.

From the Magento navigation menu, Stores > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options.

You should be able to change the value here to 'No' and it will keep the customer on the same page once they have logged in to their account.